# Backup db by using sqlmaint.exe: -CkDB -BkUpOnlyIfClean

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005 sqlmaint.exe to backup remote sql server databases. Normally I have set up the backup with -CkDB -BkUpOnlyIfClean options.

```
sqlmaint.exe -S IPForRemote\SLQInstance -U user -P pwd -D db -CkDB -BkUpOnlyIfClean 
   -Rpt C:\LocalPath\MSSQL_Backup\Log\dbbackup.log -VrfyBackup -BkUpMedia DISK 
   -BkUpDB C:\RemotePath\MSSQL_Backup -DelBkUps 3days -DelTxtRpt 3weeks 
   -HtmlRpt C:\LocalPath\MSSQL_Backup\HTMLRpt\dbbackup.html -DelHtmlRpt -3weeks
```

This one works fine form most of SQL server databases. Today I tried to do the same back against to another SQL Server Express database. I could not do the backup with these options set. The backup fails at the first step:

```
[1] Database ctc_config: Check Data and Index Linkage...
```

The following is the error message:

> [Microsoft SQL-DMO (ODBC SQLState:
>   42000)] Error 5030: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The
>   database could not be exclusively
>   locked to perform the operation.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Check statement
>   aborted. The database could not be
>   checked as a database snapshot could
>   not be created and the database or
>   table could not be locked. See Books
>   Online for details of when this
>   behavior is expected and what
>   workarounds exist. Also see previous
>   errors for more details.

If I don't include them, the back is fine. The database is very similar to the databases I have done before.

I also tried to use SQL Management Studio to do the back on that remote PC, by invoking db's context menu: task->backup.... It works fine. I guess the backup from studio may not include the checking.

I am not sure if the database has some issues or not. I really would like to backup the db with integrity checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend moving away from sqlmaint.exe (will get deprecated) and move to SQLCMD in combination with actual SQL queries
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -o <MyOutput.rpt>
```

I have scheduled DBCC CHECKDB as scheduled jobs weekly, you shouldn't need to check it every time you back up